# Project doing in mvc pattern using cairngorm framework

Tags: apache-flex, flash, model-view-controller, frameworks, cairngorm

hii ..
I wish to do my project in mvc pattern. so I chose cairngorm framework and just read some of the document about this framework.But I cant understand deeply to do project using this framework. Have any methods or examples to study doing project in cairngorm framework??
If u can pleas help me.

Comment: I would recommend pureMVC instead. The cairngorm framework has some really nasty things related to how the view is coupled. That being said, if you really want to stick to cairngorm check out the examples on Adobe's site.

Comment: depends on what type of project you are looking at. One could give a minimalist example but I am not sure it will help that much. let us know if a minimalist example showing the bare minimum is what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to check out the [Cairngorm Diagram Explorer](http://robsondesign.com/demo/cairngorm_diagram_explorer/). It is an interactive app that carries you though the Cairngorm process. The example in this case being a contact list. Click on any object in the diagram to see the as code equivalent.